# Quicksort getting rid of Keys after sorting

Tags: php, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to run a recursive quick sort on an array with a list of countries and their number of athletes

For example this input:

```
[Iran, Islamic Republic Of] => 38
[Italy] => 257
[Brazil] => 246
[Norway] => 114
[Algeria] => 17
[Bulgaria] => 65
[Malaysia] => 29
```

I am trying to sort the information from highest to lowest using this function:

```
function quicksort($array)
{
    if (count($array) == 0) {
        return array();
    }

    $pivot = array_shift($array); //Array_shift is getting rid of keys I need the keys to identify the numbers
    $left = $right = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $object){
        if ($object > $pivot) {
            $left[$key] = $object;
        } else {
            $right[$key] = $object;
        }
    }

    return array_merge(quicksort($left), array($pivot), quicksort($right));
}
```

The output is:

```
[2] => 520
[3] => 512
[4] => 482
[5] => 448
[6] => 417
[7] => 378
[8] => 357
```

The problem is that I'm losing the keys (countries) and I'm left with only the values of each key.

Comment: Any specific reason you're not using one of the provided sorting functions?

Comment: Use [arsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)

Comment: I can't i have to implement binary sort

Comment: If you really need the keys, change `$pivot = array_shift($array);` to `$pivotKey = key($array); $pivot = array_shift($array);` to get the key of the shifted element in $pivotKey

Comment: Yeah, i have to implement multiple things such as binary search recursion and other things part of the assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the key of the pivot in the last line of the function (the line starting with `return`). This should work:

```
function quicksort($array)
{
    if (count($array) == 0) {
        return array();
    }

    reset($array); // Reset array pointer to the first element
    $pivotkey = key($array); // Get the key of that first element
    $pivot = array_shift($array); // Het it's value and remove it

    $left = $right = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value > $pivot) {
            $left[$key] = $value;
        } else {
            $right[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return array_merge(quicksort($left), array($pivotkey => $pivot), quicksort($right));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the built-in array sorting functions. `arsort()` should do the trick.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php